# Should I use em or % for margins and paddings?

Tags: css

Should I use em or % for margins and paddings? For example:

```
    .box{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20%;
        background: #bada55;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8t4a9shn/

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real answer to that as `em` and `%` or completely different units:

- `em` is relative to the font size of the parent element
- `%` is relative to the viewport width or height

So it always depends on your use case.

Answer (score -1):

Use in em or px, 
because these value is static, 
means not change with screen Resolution and Size.
but % is changeable according to screen Resolution and Size.

If you have any other doubt please explain properly.